# Reading a Matrix "From Workspace" and insert the values in other variable through "to workspace"

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, simulink, workspace

I'm trying to read an array from the workspace through the "From Workspace" function by passing it in the "Matlab Function" block whose input must equal the output, finally the value should be entered in another "To Workspace" variable, as in the image Next.

The problem is only 1, if the matrix is `x = [1 2 3 4 5]`, it ignores the first value of the array, i.e, `1`, and starts from the second value in case `2`. Thus the output value is:

```
simout = [2 3 4 5]
```

How to solve without adding a "zero" value in the array?

[image: SimulinkModel]

Answer (score 2):

As per the [From Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) documentation, if the input is

- A two-dimensional matrix: You can use a matrix to specify only one-
  dimensional signals. The first element of each matrix row is a timestamp.
  The rest of each row is a scalar or vector of signal values.

That is, the `1` in your input is being treated as a timestamp.  If your whole data set is the vector `x = 1:5` then just use a [Constant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/constant.html) block.  If not, then be more specific in your question.